# Put Text at the end of Arrow in Graphics3d

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to label the thrusters on my spaceship using arrows. The arrows appear and so does the text, but I'd like to put the text at the end of the arrows instead of in the middle of the ship. [image: Ship with arrows]

You can see what I mean here. My code is this:
[image: Code]

How do I go about this?

Comment: Post actual code in code blocks that can be copied and pasted into a Mma notebook rather than images of a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

```
myarrow[begin_List, end_List, mytext_String] := Graphics3D[
  {Arrow[{begin, end}], 
   Text[Style[mytext, 14], end]}]
```

You can fine tune this (size, placement, etc.) to fit your needs.